# Adding dynamic inputs to a symbol in an animate html5 document

Tags: javascript, html, adobe-animate

Am trying to add an input to a symbol in an html5 file using adobe animate, but the inputs is not seen on stage but I can see it when i console log Here is the script;

```
var symbolInstance = this.pos;

var inputElement = document.createElement("input");
inputElement.type = "text";

var domElement = new createjs.DOMElement(inputElement);
symbolInstance.addChild(domElement);
```

Am expecting to see the input on stage